# How to fetch data of three level categories (Category,SubCategory,SubCategoryThree) and display relative data under selected category

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables. The structure is:

```
1. categories

    id - integer

    name - string

2. sub_Categories

    id - integer

    category_id - integer

    name - string


3. sub_catergory_threes

    id - integer

    sub_Category_id - integer

    name- string
```

Now I want to show three level categories like, Category and when hover on any category item, Sub Categories of that category shows and when hover on any SubCategory item, Sub_Categories_Three of that SubCategory shows

> im using laravel eloquent here are My Models
>
> Category Model

```
public function subcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory');
}
```

> SubCategory Model

```
public function subcategoriesthree(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategoryThree');
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

> SubCategoriesThree Model

```
public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ELoquent relationship to load all the related data

```
$categories = App\Category::with('subcategories.subcategoriesthree')->get();
```

This will load all the categories along with its subcategories and subsubcategories

If you need to load it dynamically, then in your controller you can use

```
public function loadSubCategory($categoryId)
{
    $category = App\Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
    $subcategories = $category->subcategories()->get();
    return $subcategories;
}

public function loadSubSubCategory($subcategoryId)
{
    $subcategory = App\SubCategory::findOrFail($subcategoryId);
    $subsubcategories = $subcategory->subcategoriesthree()->get();
    return $subsubcategories;
}
```

Comment: yes it display all the record form three tables (Thanx, new lesson), but i want to work on hover, and only show subcategories of Category selected item.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check if that works

Comment: Thank you very much @mare99 this are working as i want. thank you again

Comment: `$categories = App\Category::with('subcategories.subcategoriesthree')->get();` this save life

Answer (score 1):

So you can edit your model like this:

**SubCategory**

```
public function subcategoriesthree(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategoryThree');
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

**SubCategoriesThree**

```
public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory', 'sub_Category_id');
}
```

And in your controller:

```
$categories = Category::with(['subcategories', 'subcategories.subcategoriesthree'])->get();
```

And after that you can `dd($categories)` and see under `subcategories` are `subcategoriesthree`.

Comment: Can you show your `dd($categories)` and what do you expect?

Comment: Thank you very much @mare99 this are working as i want.

Comment: You are welcome. Just don't forget to mark answer. @AliRaza